# Converting a Heap table to Clustered table

Tags: sql-server, indexing, clustered-index

Problem Overview:

We have created a table without a clustered index on Id column and inserted millions of data into that table. When I check the indexes, it shows NULL for the index name. With some googling, it looks like a heap table. When I created a clustered index on this table, it shows two indexes with the same name. For the heap table select, and updates are really slow but insertions are really fast.

[image]

Is there anyway to remove the previous index? or convert the heap table to clustered table?
Or are there any possible ways to have only the clustered index data.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anyway to remove the previous index? or convert the heap table to clustered table?

Yes.  Just create a clustered index or a clustered columnstore index on the table.

> Or are there any possible ways to have only the clustered index data.

It's quite common for a table to have only a single Clustered Index.

Comment: I created a clustered index on that table. now It shows two indexes with the same name. Index Id and the index name both are same

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your query.  An index is uniquely identified by the (object_id,index_id).  A clustered index will have index_id=1, a heap index_id=0, and non-clustered indexes index_id>1.